# How can I worship Dyaus the Sky god?

Tags: vedas, mantras, rig-veda

I can't find any specific hymns dedicated to him in the Rigveda. Are there any mantras or richas dedicated to him in our Shastra?

Comment: Isn't he referred as "Akasha"?

Comment: Why do you want to worship him? Also, you have to initiated to recite mantras.

Comment: You can go through [this article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyaus).  It explains which verses from Rig veda mention Dyaus.  If you mean Sky God as Heaven and his wife as Earth,  parents of all gods, this [159](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv01159.htm)  and [160](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv01160.htm)    Hymns in 1st Manadala of Rig veda praise them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Are there any mantras or richas dedicated to him in our Shastra?

Dyaus is considered as the god of sky in our scriptures.Dyauṣ is the father, the Sky, who impregnated Pṛthivī, the earth and mother, in the form of rains. He is the father of Indra (future king of the Gods, and lord of rain), Agni (Fire) and Ushas (the Dawn), and is said to have caused the subsequent growth of the flora and fauna on the earth.
Dyauṣ is mentioned in five verses of the Rig Veda in simple invocations. In the RV Hymn 1.89, Dyauṣ is first mentioned by name and given the title of Father Heaven (as opposed to heavenly father which is read differently).
blessings.

> May Earth our Mother, and our **Father Heaven Dyaus,** give it to us &, may the Wind waft to us that pleasant medicine. **Rigved 1:89:4**
>
> Sweet be the night and sweet the dawns, sweet the terrestrial atmosphere;Sweet be our Father Heaven, **Dyaus** to us.**Rigved 1:90:7**
>
> **Dyaus is my Father**, my begetter: kinship is here. This great earth is my kin and Mother.Between the wide-spread world-halves is the birth-place: the Father laid the Daughter's germ within it.**Rigved 1;164:33**
>
> Let Agni -for he knows the way- conduct us to all that he enjoys of God-sent riches, What all the Immortals have prepared with wisdom, **Dyaus,** Sire, Begetter, raining down true blessings.**Rigved 4:1:10**
>
> **Thy Father Dyaus** esteemed himself a hero: most noble was the work of Indra's Maker, His who begat the strong bolt's Lord who roareth, immovable like earth from her foundation.**Rigved 4:17:4**

Even after it, no verse is independently dedicated to dyaus. He appears mostly in the hymns of Visvedeva, Agni and Indra.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

There is a sūkta dedicated to dyaus and pṛthivī in Tāittirīya Saṁhitā  4.1.11. It occurs just after the sāvitrī.

References: https://titus.uni-frankfurt.de/texte/etcs/ind/aind/ved/yvs/ts/ts.htm